# Combine two data frames by matching index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have a data frame that has the form:

```
index predicted
   1     1
   2     1
   3     0
   4     0
   5     1
```

And another that has the form:

```
index actual
   2    1
   4    0
```

I want the data frame:

```
index predicted actual
   1     1       nan
   2     1       1
   3     0       nan
   4     0       0
   5     1       nan
```

I've tried `pd.concat([df1,df2], on="index", how="left")` and `pd.merge(df1, df2, axis=1)`

Both give the dataframe:

```
index predicted actual
   1     1       1
   2     1       0
   3     0       nan
   4     0       nan
   5     1       nan
```

How can I get the data frame I need.  Also thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **pd.merge()** setting the parameters **left_index = True** and **right_index = True**

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'predicted': [1,1,0,0,1]}, index = (1,2,3,4,5))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'actual': [1,0]}, index = (2,4))

pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

This will merge the two dataframes on index and produce the intended result required.

```
index   predicted   actual
1       1           NaN
2       1           1.0
3       0           NaN
4       0           0.0
5       1           NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure that your index column is actually the `df.index`, pd.concat should work:

```
import pandas as pd

left = pd.DataFrame({"predicted": [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]}, index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
right = pd.DataFrame({"actual": [1, 0]}, index=[2, 4])

out = pd.concat([left, right], axis=1)
```

```
   predicted  actual
1          1     NaN
2          1     1.0
3          0     NaN
4          0     0.0
5          1     NaN
```

If they're just columns, such as the following:

```
left = left.reset_index(names="index")
right = right.reset_index(names="index")
```

then you can use:

```
left.merge(right, on="index", how="left")
```

```
   index  predicted  actual
0      1          1     NaN
1      2          1     1.0
2      3          0     NaN
3      4          0     0.0
4      5          1     NaN
```

Comment: Okay yeah this was definitely the problem!  The data frames I'm using are subsets of bigger ones it looks like you're right, the index was just a column and not it's index.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create index as a temporary column then left join using that then set it as index.

```py
predict_df = pd.DataFrame({'predicted': [1,1,0,0,1]}, index=range(1,6))
actual_df = pd.DataFrame({'actual': [1,0]}, index=[2,4])

pd.merge(
    left=predict_df.reset_index(),
    right=actual_df.reset_index(),
    how='left',
    on='index'
).set_index('index')
```

```py
      predicted actual
index       
1     1         NaN
2     1         1.0
3     0         NaN
4     0         0.0
5     1         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.join(df2)
```

out:

```
predicted  actual
1          1     NaN
2          1     1.0
3          0     NaN
4          0     0.0
5          1     NaN
```

Comment: Interesting, that didn't work on my end, I'll keep grinding at it, but I think it's an indexing issue.

Comment: ADD KEY ARGUMENT IS YOUR INDEX